# "from" field of comments on my Facebook Page are partially missing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API to list all comments of posts of my Facebook page by using this call

```
/v3.1/me?fields=posts{comments{from,message,created_time,comments{from,message,created_time}}}
```

I am admin of the page and I use Page Access token for API calls.

This is what I get (Blacked out some details for privacy reasons)

```
{
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "comments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "from": {
                "name": "██P1██",
                "id": "███6166"
              },
              "message": "Ich poste als ██P1██",
              "created_time": "2018-08-02T08:58:47+0000",
              "id": "2021000871244096_2067310823279767"
            },
            {
              "from": {
                "name": "██U1██",
                "id": "███8640"
              },
              "message": "Ich poste als ██U1██",
              "created_time": "2018-08-02T08:59:33+0000",
              "id": "2021000871244096_2067311606613022"
            },
            {
              "from": {
                "name": "██P1██",
                "id": "███6166"
              },
              "message": "Host an Schülling für mi?",
              "created_time": "2018-08-02T09:00:23+0000",
              "id": "2021000871244096_2067312356612947"
            },
            {
              "from": {
                "name": "██U2██",
                "id": "███4255"
              },
              "message": "Ich bin’s der echte ██U2██.",
              "created_time": "2018-08-02T09:02:16+0000",
              "id": "2021000871244096_2067313976612785"
            },
            {
              "from": {
                "name": "██U3██",
                "id": "███2062"
              },
              "message": "It's a me! ██U3██",
              "created_time": "2018-08-02T09:03:43+0000",
              "id": "2021000871244096_2067315156612667"
            },
            {
              "message": "such a lonely boat ",
              "created_time": "2018-08-02T09:15:12+0000",
              "id": "2021000871244096_2067325063278343"
            },
            {
              "message": "Der Gerät schneidet das Fleisch schweißfrei.",
              "created_time": "2018-08-02T09:18:23+0000",
              "comments": {
                "data": [
                  {
                    "from": {
                      "name": "██P1██",
                      "id": "███6166"
                    },
                    "message": "Der Gerät ist vor die Chef in Geschäft!",
                    "created_time": "2018-08-02T09:23:02+0000",
                    "id": "2021000871244096_2067334489944067"
                  }
                ],
                "paging": {
                  "cursors": {
                    "before": "QVFIUlpUWEduOVRaRGFITEFGajgxaXNadkhMVDVjbUwxMGRuelhRVzdNUHprak81U3dIVTFoQmQydkR1U0I2T09nMVAxcVVaN2Y3S1oyeUMyVVVTTVpMRm5B",
                    "after": "QVFIUlpUWEduOVRaRGFITEFGajgxaXNadkhMVDVjbUwxMGRuelhRVzdNUHprak81U3dIVTFoQmQydkR1U0I2T09nMVAxcVVaN2Y3S1oyeUMyVVVTTVpMRm5B"
                  }
                }
              },
              "id": "2021000871244096_2067330469944469"
            },
            {
              "message": "",
              "created_time": "2018-08-02T09:19:34+0000",
              "id": "2021000871244096_2067331519944364"
            },
            {
              "message": "",
              "created_time": "2018-08-09T09:01:43+0000",
              "id": "2021000871244096_2079260155418167"
            },
            {
              "message": "Heyho. Ich bins",
              "created_time": "2018-08-09T09:10:48+0000",
              "id": "2021000871244096_2079269595417223"
            },
            {
              "message": "Heyho. Ich bin nochmal",
              "created_time": "2018-08-09T09:11:49+0000",
              "id": "2021000871244096_2079270622083787"
            }
          ],
          "paging": {
            "cursors": {
              "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANakEyTWpVMU56STNNemMxTlRFeU1qb3hOVE15T1RVMk5UTXgZD",
              "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANakEzT1RJM01EWXlNakE0TXpjNE56b3hOVE16T0RBMU9UQTUZD"
            }
          }
        },
        "id": "195180353826166_2021000871244096"
      },
      {
        "id": "195180353826166_227658903911644"
      },
      {
        "id": "195180353826166_147002885360315"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5TXhPVFV4T0RBek5UTTRNall4TmpZANk5ESXpNalV5TXpjMU5qZA3hPVFUwTWpnek5ROE1ZAWEJwWDNOMGIzSjVYMmxrRHlBeE9UVXhPREF6TlRNNE1qWXhOalpmTWpBeU1UQXdNRGczTVRJME5EQTVOZAzhFZAEdsdFpRWmJQT2p6QVE9PQZDZD",
        "after": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5UXhPVFV4T0RBek5UTTRNall4TmpZANkxUVTBNamN3T0RrMU16QXlNVE15TWpJNU1UWVBER0ZA3YVY5emRHOXllVjlwWkE4ZAk1UazFNVGd3TXpVek9ESTJNVFkyWHpFME56QXdNamc0TlRNMk1ETXhOUThFZAEdsdFpRWk5XbFQxQVE9PQZDZD"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "195180353826166"
}
```

As you can see, for some comments, the "from" field is missing and I don't know why (Example: comment with id 2021000871244096_2067325063278343 ("such a lonely boat ")).

- P1 is the page itself
- U1, U2 are users with admin rights
- U3 is a normal user who liked the page

The author of `2021000871244096_2067325063278343` hasn't liked the page but the author of `2021000871244096_2079269595417223` has liked it afterwards (comment `2021000871244096_2079270622083787`).

Is there any way to get the names of all users who comment on my page?

Answer (score 0):

Reached out to FB-Dev-Group and FB-Platform Support. They don't include everything due to user settings and privacy reasons
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1618790588170504/

Plus, your app needs to be approved and live (mine is still in development mode)
https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1897897803587058